# Geth is stuck 60-100 blocks behind main net for 3 weeks, how can I solve this issue?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, full-node, openblockchain

I've been trying to sync the Ethereum Blockchain using Geth and as a full node on my MacOS for almost 3 weeks now, however I am still stuck 60-100 blocks behind the main net, as you can see below:

currentBlock: 12256818,
highestBlock: 12256898,
knownStates: 534379826,
pulledStates: 534200595,
startingBlock: 0

My MacOS has the following specifications:

Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-core Intel Core i7
Memory: 32 GB RAM

it should be strong enough to sync the blockchain!

Please advise on what to do? should I switch to Parity?

Comment: Do you have an SSD or HDD? HDDs aren't fast enough to keep up.

Comment: I have SSD. I deleted the blockchain and re-ddi the whole process but this time I used cash: 2048. It sinked faster but then it failed giving me this message:  Failed to write block data to ancient store err="appending unexpected item: want 5704756, have 5704757"